# i can not show arabic-indic numbers in google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

is it possiable to format the vaxis in google chart to arabic-indic 
this is the officially documentation :

[Google chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

however i looked through the whole documentation i did not find anything

[image]

i have no problem with xaxis the problem with vertical , i need them in format like ١،٢،٣...

Comment: @WhiteHat thank you , however i already set the locale in ar however just the x-axis changes ,but the v-axis still the same

Comment: Could you check whether v46 does the right thing?  There are some changes in how localization is done.

Comment: @dlaliberte actually nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, but you'll have to use an undocumented feature, which will be documented at some point.  You'll need to make this call sometime before you draw your chart.

```
   google.visualization.NumberFormat.useNativeCharactersIfAvailable(true);
```

This works with material charts prior to v46, and also in classic charts starting with v46.  See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/6k8vdgz7/

You may see some problems depending on what formatting options you also specify.

Comment: Great.  But let's delete this duplicate question in favor of the better one at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449241   Attn: martijn-pieters