# showing line chart vertical axis in another number language

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, frontend, web-frontend

i am trying to make vertical axis labeled in indian ١،٢،٣ and plotted in Indian too  , however it seems it has no meaning for computer , since there is no native encoding for arabic number , however in terms of english 0,1,2,3... you can do calculations no problem in that , the problem i must to show indian-arabic values

[image]

this line chart is done by google Visualization api  , the last version 46.0 , and the lang is ar however the result is not as i aimed for , the vaxis should be in ١،٢،٣ and the plotted values

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423807 but your question is better here, so I will move my answer here too.

Comment: @martijn-pieters if you are paying attention, this question is the better stated question, so you should have deleted my answer to the duplicate, not this one.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a slightly modified answer to the duplicate question posted at stackoverflow.com/questions/46423807.  Martijn Pieters, if you are paying attention, please delete that question instead of this one.)

There is a solution, but you'll have to use an undocumented feature, which will be documented at some point. You'll need to make this call sometime before you draw your chart.

```
google.visualization.NumberFormat.useNativeCharactersIfAvailable(true);
```

This works with material charts prior to v46, and also in classic charts starting with v46. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/6k8vdgz7/

You may see some problems depending on what formatting options you also specify.